# ruby - active record reputation system (hiding votes button)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have the active record reputation system working however i cant seem to hide the voting button once a user has voted for something.

in user.rb i have a voted for method

```
has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source
def voted_for?(review)
evaluations.where(target_type: review.class, target_id: review.id).present?
end
```

then in a reviews show page i have the following code to hide the buttons if the 'if' statements evaluates to true

```
<% if User.find(session[:user_id]) &&
!User.find(session[:user_id]).voted_for(@review)%>
<h3> Vote: 
<%= link_to "Up", vote_review_path(@review, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
||
<%= link_to "Down", vote_review_path(@review, type: "down"), method: "post" %></h3>
<% end %>
```

The buttons still show up regardless. I've been following railscast and in that video they used current_user however i've user the User.find(session[:user_id]) to identify the user (current_user isn't defined and i always get the error "*undefined local variable or method `current_user'*"

Comment: Are you sure the votes are stored? Did you check the database?

Comment: yes they appear to be in the database, for rs_evaluation it has 12 rows.

Comment: What kind of values do you have in target_type?

Comment: for target_type it says 'Review' for each row

Comment: Hm, does it work if you do `target_type: review.class.to_s` instead of `target_type: review.class`?

Comment: everything remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your application_helper.rb:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end

def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end
```

Now you can use `current_user` and `logged_in?` in your views.

```
<% if logged_in? && !current_user.voted_for?(@review)%>
<h3> Vote: 
<%= link_to "Up", vote_review_path(@review, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
||
<%= link_to "Down", vote_review_path(@review, type: "down"), method: "post" %></h3>
<% end %>

def voted_for?(review)
  evaluations.where(target_type: review.class, target_id: review.id).count > 0
end
```

Comment: thanks, but it still shows up with the buttons even if the user has voted

Comment: I edited the answer to include a change to the `voted_for?` method.

Comment: Then something is up with your query.  It must be returning rows at all time.

Comment: is there another way to just disable the buttons or maybe put in a validation to throw an error anything that alerts the user that they've already voted for a review.

Answer (score 0):

if your Review class has

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

you can get all evaluations(reputation records) with

```
object.evaluations
```

So to determine whether there was some votes, by particular user you may use

```
class Review
    def was_vouted_by? user
        self.evaluations.find_by_source_id(user.id)
    end
 end
```

**find_by_source_id** - will return **record** which ruby evaluates to true, or **nil** which ruby evaluates to false